# Android loading images from url doesnt update fragments directly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, picasso, android-fragmentactivity

I am using a pager to controll multiple fragments, count depends on data input. Each fragment displays infos about a person, also a image. I am loading the image per Picasso library in each fragment. But the fragment doesnt update after the image was loaded and set to the ImageView, so it doesnt appear on the screen. If I am closing the fragments and open them again, all images are shown.

Is it possbile to update the fragments after loaded the images, so the images appear directly on the screen?

```
private void setHeaderImage() {
    if (stolperstein.isImageHeaderUrl()) {
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(stolperstein.getImageHeaderUrl()).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom arg1) {
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                user_header_photo.setBackground(drawable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have some listeners or adapters?

Comment: implements Runnable, View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener

Comment: Though I don't have an idea, where're you trying to load the images (Fragments or Activity). You can either opt to load images in respective fragment where you want to display the images or load it in activity but then you need to tell your adapter attached to the `viewpager` that a new data is available, to be precise `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: I use the AppIntro lib, in this way I create slider fragments on the AppIntro activity. I load the images with the method setHeaderImage() above in the fragment class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing in the last part of your code , but if user_header_photo is an ImageView you can load it directly into it:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(stolperstein.getImageHeaderUrl()).into(user_header_photo)
```

Comment: I dont understand the reason, but this is working. Thanks